# [Vector spaces ]Why does the matrix of a linear transformation from $V$ ( of dim $n$) to $W$ ( of dim $p$) have $p$ rows?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

The reference I am reading ( Alain Troesch's Algebra Course for French Higher Mathematics Classes)
defines the matrix of a linear transformation from a vector space $V$ with basis  $B= \{b_1, ...b_n\}$ to a vector space $W$ of basis $C= \{ c_1, ...c_p\}$  as :

> the matrix  having as columns the column vectors $[f(b_1)], [f(b_2)]
>  ... [f(b_n)]$

where these vectors are the cordinate vectors of the images $f(b_1) ... f(b_n)$  in the basis of $W$, namely in basis $C$.

Since there are $n$ elements in basis $B$, and since each one of these elements is assigned an image under $f$, I can see that there are $n$ coordinate vectors , and therefore $n$ columns in the desired matrix.

But I can't manage to see why there are $p$ rows in this matrix.

In other words , why should each coordinate vector have $p$ rows?

Comment: can you start by writing the definition of 'coordinate vector (with respect to a basis)'? If you understand the definition, you'll have answered your question.

Comment: Because $f(b_i)\in W$, and the dimension of $W$ is equal to $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already commented, it's because $W$ is $p$-dimensional, so each image vector $f(b_i)$ has $p$ coordinates with respect to the basis $c_1,\ldots,c_p$, and therefore $p$ rows in the matrix.

Another way to read your "why" question might be: why do we form a $p\times n$ matrix here instead of forming an $n\times p$ matrix with the coordinates of each vector $f(b_i)$ arranged horizontally in rows? The answer is that, when using "left-hand" function notation in which we write $f(b_i)$ instead of $(b_i)f$, the $p\times n$ matrix is the "natural" choice because it assures that
$$[f(x)]=[f][x]$$
under the ordinary convention for matrix multiplication, where I'm here using brackets to denote the matrix of $f$ and the coordinate column vectors relative to the chosen bases.